# wrapping a listviewBuilder inside of Column?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I wish a good day.i m struggling to wrap a ListView.builder inside of a column.
every time I try to fix it I get this exception :

```
 The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
flutter:   RenderViewport#c3792 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   creator: Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#b696d] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
flutter:   RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#65964] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope
flutter:   ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#f3a27] ← Scrollable ← PrimaryScrollController ← ListView ← ⋯
flutter:   parentData: <none> (can use size)
flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=327.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
flutter:   size: MISSING
flutter:   axisDirection: down
flutter:   crossAxisDirection: right
flutter:   offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#60171(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null,
flutter:   ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> BouncingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#63b9f,
flutter:   ScrollDirection.idle)
flutter:   anchor: 0.0
flutter: This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
flutter:   RenderSliverPadding#e4dfb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:     RenderSliverList#17862 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#c3792 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#c3792 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#8fccb relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#cbeea relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#0b306 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on null.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
```

this is my code :

```
Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _messages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, position) {

                print(_messages.length);
                return Center(child: Text(_messages[position]));
              }),
            )
          ]))
```

if there's anyone who can help me i will be very thankful.

Comment: wrap your second `Padding` in [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget.

Comment: thank u bro , it works for me.

Comment: Glad it helped! Do you mind if I post this as an answer?

Comment: yeah, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, wrapping the second `Padding` inside of [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget does the job.